# Shared Preferences overwrite last value on every key before commit() or Apply()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, key-value

I'm trying to save two Boolean value over two different keys but every-time when i save value in the key it overwrites key with last value only.

Below is the function call to save the value

```
AssignRegistrationFun manage =
    new AssignRegistrationFun(getApplicationContext());
manage.ChangeDataState(false,true);
```

Below is the function call in if condition to check the data state...
at this function call it returns true even though i set the first value to false

```
if(manage.checkDataChanged("External"))
```

below is function definition with class details

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

public class AssignRegistrationFun {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    Editor  editor;
    Context _context;
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
    private static final String PREF_NAME ="Tester";
    private static final String EXTERNAL_DATA = "true";
    private static final String INTERNAL_DATA = "true";

    public AssignRegistrationFun(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void ChangeDataState(boolean EX_state,boolean IN_state){
        editor.putBoolean(EXTERNAL_DATA,EX_state);
        editor.putBoolean(INTERNAL_DATA,IN_state);
        editor.commit();//even editor.apply() not works     
    }

    public boolean checkDataChanged(String type){
        if(type.equals("External")) 
            return pref.getBoolean(EXTERNAL_DATA,false);
        else
            return pref.getBoolean(INTERNAL_DATA,false);
    }

}
```

please help me out thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your `EXTERNAL_DATA` and `INTERNAL_DATA` are set to the same string value: `"true"`, so when you assing to one, you overwrite the value of the other.

Solution: use different values, e.g.:

```
private static final String EXTERNAL_DATA = "external";
private static final String INTERNAL_DATA = "internal";
```

Comment: I love you. 5 days looking for this. thanks Attila!!!